# How can I take a texture from a image and convert that into a big image with the same texture in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing

Suppose I have the image below and I want to use the soil colored portion in it to create a another image of 240x240 having this texture only. I have the mask for the soiled portion as well.
[image]

Comment: You can try to replicate the content of the mask with random translation and rotation, until you cover the entire image. Composite with an opacity the decreases from the center to the border of the mask. Finally, modulate with a variable intensity to avoid a too flat impression.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the suggestions. Could you please point to a resource/example doing the same?

Comment: Not at all, I just figured this out.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do Poisson Seamless Blending in Python/OpenCV according to [http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall07/Papers/Perez03.pdf](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emisha/Fall07/Papers/Perez03.pdf). (See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/df/da0/group__photo__clone.html#ga2bf426e4c93a6b1f21705513dfeca49d). But I tried it and it does not seem to work for this situation for my version of OpenCV 4.6.0

But if you are willing to use another software tool, such as Imagemagick (called from Python using a subprocess call) or Python Wand, which is based upon Imagemagick (assuming it is up to date with Imagemagick), then the following works:

Input Crop of Your Texture:

[image]

The idea is to make each side of the border the average of it and its opposite side as the background image.  The mask is just a white image of the same size with the edges black. In Imagemagick, seamless blending is just another option to -compose ... -composite. The following creates the background image and the mask and then composites them and then tiles it out in a 3x3 array.

```
magick old_texture.png +write mpr:img \
\( mpr:img -gravity east -crop 1x+0+0 +repage \) \
\( mpr:img -gravity west -crop 1x+0+0 +repage \) \
\( mpr:img -gravity north -crop x1+0+0 +repage \) \
\( mpr:img -gravity south -crop x1+0+0 +repage \) \
\( \
-clone 1,2 -evaluate-sequence mean +write mpr:LR +delete \
-clone 3,4 -evaluate-sequence mean +write mpr:TB +delete \
\) \
-delete 0-4 \
mpr:LR \( mpr:img -shave 1x0 \) mpr:LR +append \
-shave 0x1 mpr:TB +swap mpr:TB -append \
old_texture_background.png

magick old_texture.png -fill white -colorize 100 \
-shave 1x1 -bordercolor black -border 1 \
old_texture_mask.png

magick old_texture_background.png old_texture.png old_texture_mask.png \
-define compose:args=400x0.00002+100 -compose seamless-blend \
-composite \
-duplicate 2 +append \
-duplicate 2 -append \
old_texture_seamless_tiled_3x3.png
```

Background Image:

[image]

Mask Image:

[image]

Resulting 3x3 Tiled Seamless Blend:

[image]

**ADDITION**

If I crop inside your region for a 24x24 section:

[image]

And run:

```
magick old_texture2.png +write mpr:img \
\( mpr:img -gravity east -crop 1x+0+0 +repage \) \
\( mpr:img -gravity west -crop 1x+0+0 +repage \) \
\( mpr:img -gravity north -crop x1+0+0 +repage \) \
\( mpr:img -gravity south -crop x1+0+0 +repage \) \
\( \
-clone 1,2 -evaluate-sequence mean +write mpr:LR +delete \
-clone 3,4 -evaluate-sequence mean +write mpr:TB +delete \
\) \
-delete 0-4 \
mpr:LR \( mpr:img -shave 1x0 \) mpr:LR +append \
-shave x1 mpr:TB +swap mpr:TB -append \
old_texture2_background.png

magick old_texture2.png -fill white -colorize 100 \
-shave 1x1 -bordercolor black -border 1 \
old_texture2_mask.png

magick old_texture2_background.png old_texture2.png old_texture2_mask.png \
-define compose:args=400x0.00002+100 -compose seamless-blend \
-composite \
-duplicate 9 +append \
-duplicate 9 -append \
old_texture_seamless_tiled_10x10.png
```

The Result is (240x240):

[image]

Comment: Actually I wanted to do for the soil portion only i.e. the brown part with python if possible.

Comment: See the ADDITION in my answer.